# C # combobox items selection is empty in first attempt

Tags: c#, combobox

In my code, selection of 2nd combobox items list depends on first combobox item selection, but  in 1st click of first combobox item selection, i get the empty string. in 2nd attempt i get the required value in 2nd combobox. plz help

```
private void comboCatSOP_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
                try
                {
                    string cbi  = this.comboCatSOP.GetItemText(this.comboCatSOP.SelectedItem);
                    MessageBox.Show(cbi);

                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
                    {
                        string CmdString = "select Category from Category";
                        comboCatSOP.Items.Clear();

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, conn);
                        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Category");
                        sda.Fill(dt1);

                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
                        {
                            comboCatSOP.Items.Add(dr["Category"].ToString());
                        }

                        string CmdString2 = "select p.ModelNo from Product p inner join Category c on p.CatID=c.CatID where p.CompanyID='" + txtCompanyChangeInternal + "' and c.Category='" + cbi.ToString() + "'  group by c.CatID,p.ModelNo";

                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(CmdString2, conn);
                        SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Product");
                        sda2.Fill(dt2);

                        comboModelSOP.Items.Clear();
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
                        {
                            comboModelSOP.Items.Add(dr["ModelNo"].ToString());
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
                }

            }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `Enter` event?  Do you know when it fires?

Comment: i have used Click event and SelectionChangeCommited, but gets the same result

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataSource in Combo box

```
cmb.datasource = dt;
cmb.displaymember = "name";
cmb.valuemember = "id";
```

in query select name and id then if combo box selection change use selectedvalue.
selected value return id.

good luck to you